# Overriding an abstract method with generic signature and calling it

Tags: java, generics

Generic Interface:

```java
public interface Matcher<T> {
    public double getScore(T value1, T value2);
}
```

Two implementing classes:

```java
public StringMatcher implements Matcher<String> {
    public double getScore(String value1, String value2) {...}
}

public DateMatcher implements Matcher<Date> {
    public double getScore(Date value1, Date value2) {...}
}
```

So far everything is fine. Replacing `T` with `String` or `Date` isn't a problem.
Calling the `getScore()` method as follows also works:

```java
Matcher<String> matcher = new StringMatcher();
matcher.getScore("hello", "world");
```

Problems starts when I have a `List` of unknown `Matcher` and I want to use the `getScore()` method.

```java
public void test() {
    List<Matcher<?>> list = new ArrayList<Matcher<?>>();
    list.add(new StringMatcher());
    list.add(new DateMatcher());

    for (Matcher<?> matcher : list) {
        Object value1;
        Object value2;
        //Setting values value1 & value2 appropriate to the current matcher
        matcher.getScore(value1, value2);
    }
}
```

I can't call `matcher.getScore(value1, value2)` because it can't handle object parameters. 
And at this point I have no idea how to solve this. I want to keep the interface and the signatures of the implementing classes with their concrete types. If there is no way around type casting or throwing exceptions that's okay.

Answer (score 8):

You present a conflict between wanting type safety and not wanting it, so you'll just have to decide between them. Calling `getScore` with `Object` arguments is obviously type-unsafe.

Now, if you just want a type-unsafe trick to get around compiler/runtime errors, you can declare the list as `List<Matcher>`, which means you'll be retrieving raw `Matcher`s from it, and then you'll be allowed to pass `Object`s in. You **will** get an *unchecked cast* compiler warning, though.

Comment: +1. You were faster than me. To compare Object instances, a `Matcher<Object>` is needed. Any other type of Matcher has a good chance of throwing an exception when comparing Object instances if you don't know their type.

Answer (score 0):

It would be the best to use a capture helper, so that you can use the parameter type of the matcher (say `T`), and `value1` and `value2` will be declared to be of that type `T`.

```
private <T> double helper(Matcher<T> matcher) {
    T value1;
    T value2;
    //Setting values value1 & value2 appropriate to the current matcher
    return matcher.getScore(val1, val2);
}

public void test()
{
    List<Matcher<?>> list = new ArrayList<Matcher<?>>();
    list.add(new StringMatcher());
    list.add(new DateMatcher());

    for (Matcher<?> matcher : list) {
        helper(matcher);
    }
}
```